# Azure SQl Server Cross server Database Queries in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

hi i have create 1 database in Azure SQL server .Now i want to create procedure using link server.And my other database is on different server not on Azure.So it is giving error .Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked servers are not supported in Sql Azure. If both servers were in Azure, you could used elastic database query to do cross database queries within the SQL Azure Server.

Perhaps you could give us a clearer idea of exactly what you're trying to do, and what the exact error is?

Comment: my both database is on different server first on Azure and second on other server .I want to access second database table on Azure server